# jqGrid - Variable without value on navgrid

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I have two tables in the database, called "Forms" and "Sections", with their respective grids in "forms.php" and "sections.php".

When the user selects a row from the form's grid, and choose go to the Sections of that Form, they are listed in "sections.php". Here I get the value of the Form (sending in `postData`) doing something like `$form_id=$_POST["form_id"]`

The problem arises when I try to add/delete a new Section because the variable with the id of the Form doesn't have value in "sections.php". The primary key of the table Sections are section_id and form_id but I can't modify the DB.

I guess that in the Form's `navgrid` the value has already been lost.

I try to pass the id of the Form in the `editData` but I have not succeeded.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide code example?

Comment: I try but the editor doesn't accept the code.

Comment: Please post your code. Be a sure that you correctly format the code in editor. Here more [help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)